# WP Redirect with user nickname/username

Tags: php

i am trying to redirect the user after login/signup to profile page but not sure why it is not putting user nickname/username in url.

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
function 
aloginuser( $user_id ) {
    wp_set_current_user($user_id);
    wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id);
    wp_redirect( "/profile/$current_user->user_login" );
    exit;
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'aloginuser' );
```

It need to start a redirect to: site.com/profile/username

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing `$current_user->user_login` as string `"$current_user->user_login"` and not the value stored in the variable. You have to write it like this:

```
wp_redirect("/profile/".$current_user->user_login);
```

Also, it is necessary to move the `$current_user = wp_get_current_user();` inside the function.

Comment: Nope, It is just adding /profile/ to url not current username after signup

Comment: But it was probably a part of the problem. Maybe try moving `$current_user` inside the function?